# GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks methods not being called after connecting to the GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-api-client

I've got some code which is connecting to the GoogleApiClient but onConnected is not being called.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initGoogleApiClient();
    }

    private void initGoogleApiClient() {
        mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
                .addApi( Wearable.API )
                .build();
        mApiClient.connect(); // On completion onConnected() will be called
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }
```

None of the four @Override methods are being called, why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [addConnectionCallbacks()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#addConnectionCallbacks(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks)) and [addOnConnectionFailedListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#addOnConnectionFailedListener(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener)) on your `GoogleApiClient.Builder`:

```
mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
    .addApi( Wearable.API )
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
```