# GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks methods not called after connecting to the GoogleApiClient

Tags: google-play-services

I have this issue:

[GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks methods not being called after connecting to the GoogleApiClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053332/googleapiclient-connectioncallbacks-methods-not-being-called-after-connecting-to?rq=1)

But the callbacks have been added but still no onConnection callback and no errors why would that be? Can anyone help?

My code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient ;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initGoogleApiClient();
}

private void initGoogleApiClient() {
       mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
       .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
       .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
       .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
       .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
       .build();

       mGoogleApiClient.connect();    
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question - again. The answer is to do with setting up the developer console with a debug key:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#a_create_a_linked_application

[I can’t find the Android keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997348/i-can-t-find-the-android-keytool)

[How to obtain Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1) for OAuth 2.0 on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214467/how-to-obtain-signing-certificate-fingerprint-sha1-for-oauth-2-0-on-android)

Comment: Ok so it still doesn't work. Can someone tell me do I have to 'publish' the achievements before they work?

Comment: I'm getting logins registered in the developer console, but I'm not getting a onConnection due to the app not being configured?! The email accounts I'm using are set as tester accounts. Why would this not be working now? Help!

Answer (score 0):

It's ok I've done it! Apparently you can't just debug you app from Eclipse you have to install it with an APK otherwise it wont work. As described here:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart

Good luck to anyone else wading through all the fantastic Google documentation.

:-S